# Android 31: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Size of key not known

Tags: android

I am writing an android program dealing with RSA keys. The private key (length 2048) is imported from byte array (not generated by the device). If I use Android Studio Emulator API 31, the key can be used without problems. On a Pixel 3 hardware API 31 though, there is an exception. What is the reason?

```
----- DEVICE -----
Brand: google
Device: blueline
Model: Pixel 3
ID: SP1A.210812.016.C2
Product: blueline

----- ANDROID OS -----
Android SDK: 31
Android release: 12
Android incremental: 8618562
```

Stack trace:

```
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Size of key not known
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.initKey(AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi.java:451)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.init(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:256)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:168)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2985)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2892)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2797)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:774)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1144)
03-22 22:46:03.611 23770 23770 W System.err: at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1085)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected final void initKey(int opmode, Key key) throws InvalidKeyException {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Unsupported key: null");
    }
    if (!KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA.equalsIgnoreCase(key.getAlgorithm())) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Unsupported key algorithm: " + key.getAlgorithm()
                + ". Only " + KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA + " supported");
    }
    AndroidKeyStoreKey keystoreKey;
    if (key instanceof AndroidKeyStorePrivateKey) {
        keystoreKey = (AndroidKeyStoreKey) key;
    } else if (key instanceof AndroidKeyStorePublicKey) {
        keystoreKey = (AndroidKeyStoreKey) key;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Unsupported key type: " + key);
    }

    if (keystoreKey instanceof PrivateKey) {
        // Private key
        switch (opmode) {
            case Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE:
            case Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE:
                // Permitted
                break;
            case Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE:
            case Cipher.WRAP_MODE:
                if (!adjustConfigForEncryptingWithPrivateKey()) {
                    throw new InvalidKeyException(
                            "RSA private keys cannot be used with " + opmodeToString(opmode)
                            + " and padding "
                            + KeyProperties.EncryptionPadding.fromKeymaster(mKeymasterPadding)
                            + ". Only RSA public keys supported for this mode");
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidKeyException(
                        "RSA private keys cannot be used with opmode: " + opmode);
        }
    } else {
        // Public key
        switch (opmode) {
            case Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE:
            case Cipher.WRAP_MODE:
                // Permitted
                break;
            case Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE:
            case Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE:
                throw new InvalidKeyException(
                        "RSA public keys cannot be used with " + opmodeToString(opmode)
                        + " and padding "
                        + KeyProperties.EncryptionPadding.fromKeymaster(mKeymasterPadding)
                        + ". Only RSA private keys supported for this opmode.");
                // break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidKeyException(
                        "RSA public keys cannot be used with " + opmodeToString(opmode));
        }
    }

    long keySizeBits = -1;
    for (Authorization a : keystoreKey.getAuthorizations()) {
        if (a.keyParameter.tag == KeymasterDefs.KM_TAG_KEY_SIZE) {
            keySizeBits = KeyStore2ParameterUtils.getUnsignedInt(a);
        }
    }

    if (keySizeBits == -1) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Size of key not known");
    } else if (keySizeBits > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("Key too large: " + keySizeBits + " bits");
    }
    mModulusSizeBytes = (int) ((keySizeBits + 7) / 8);

    setKey(keystoreKey);
}
```

Go to the API level 31 source code (shown above) of `AndroidKeyStoreRSACipherSpi` and set breakpoints before it throws that `InvalidKeyException` with message "Size of key not known". Compare the run on your Pixel 3 and on your simulator. Check what's the difference in there.

Comment: The problem is, I don't own the phone, where the logcat comes from

Comment: Looks like android.system.keystore2.Authorization with key size is missing on that phone, but android.system.keystore2 is not open-sourced.